# SQL group by week with concat

Tags: mysql, sql, metabase

I have a table ("table_1") like this

```
Day         Product
2019-07-08  a
2019-07-02  b
2019-07-02  b
2019-07-01  a
2019-07-01  b
...
```

And I need this:

```
Week                        a      b
2019-07-01 to 2019-07-08    2      4
2019-07-08 to 2019-07-15    23     5
...
```

So, I am trying to approximate a solution starting with:

```
select 
   concat(Day,'to', Day + interval 6 day) AS week, 
   count(distinct Product) as Counts 
from table_1
group by week(date(Day))
```

but I get this error

```
"concat"(day, 'to', day + interval 6 day)' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause
```

I am using MySQL and Metabase

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: (and are you sure you're using MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

One solution -- if you have data for all days -- is:

```
select concat(min(Day),'to', min(Day) + interval 6 day) AS week, 
       count(distinct Product) as Counts 
from table_1
group by week(date(Day));
```

You should probably also take the year into account as well.

Comment: I get this error when I try your solution: mismatched input '6' expecting {'.', ')', ',', '[', 'AND', 'AT', 'BETWEEN', 'IN', 'IS', 'LIKE', 'NOT', 'OR', '=', NEQ, '<', '<=', '>', '>=', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '||'}

Comment: @Laura . . . MySQL supports that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Idea of using WEEK number from date is bit same as answered by Gordon and this following script will give your exact expected output. The week calculation is based on WEEK starts at SUNDAY.

```
SELECT  
CONCAT(CAST(DATE_ADD(Day, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(Day)) DAY) AS DATE),
    ' To ',
    CAST(DATE_ADD(Day, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(Day))+6 DAY) AS DATE)) Week, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Product = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as a,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Product = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as b
FROM table_1
GROUP BY 
CONCAT(CAST(DATE_ADD(Day, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(Day)) DAY) AS DATE),
    ' To ',
    CAST(DATE_ADD(Day, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(Day))+6 DAY) AS DATE))
,YEAR(Day);
```